# WordPress kills an IFRAME's apostrophes

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I'm using an IFRAME to let multiple sites embed one interactive element. On the IFRAME's [actual page](http://necir-bu.org/wp/interactives/sheriffinteract/interactive.html) it works fine, and it looks fine on another website I embedded it. But when I embed it in a WordPress blog, all my apostrophes show up as squares.

I tried removing all smart quotes and apostrophes with "dumb" quotes, no luck.

I tried replacing all the apostrophes with ' and, again, no luck

Any clues what my cause this?

The IFRAME code:

```
<iframe
  src="http://necir-bu.org/wp/interactives/sheriffinteract/interactive.html"
  name="interactive" scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0" marginheight="5"
  align="center" vspace="5"
  widtha"590px" height="720px"></iframe>
```

And you can see the interactive code by just viewing the first link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an encoding problem. You probably should [configure](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/utf-8-encoding-not-actually-set-in-browser) your blog to use the `UTF-8` encoding.

Try adding the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic, I checked both places and it was already encoded in UTF-8. I added that into the IFRAMEs source, however, and it took care of all the apostrophes but not the quotation marks or dashes.

Comment: So it was an encoding problem, on the IFRAME's end. Added it to the top of the other page and (eventually) everything worked fine.